# In Rev 2:28 What does it mean to be given the bright morning star?

Tags: revelation, symbolism

What does it mean to receive the morning star in Rev 2:28?

Answer (score 3):

## Isaiah 14:12 "morning star" = "rule over nations"

*Always look back to "first mention" or "earlier" mention, then notice **trends***

**Isaiah 14:12** ([NASB](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah%2014%3A12&version=NASB), emphasis added)

> How ***you*** have fallen from heaven,
>
> O ***star of the morning***, son of the dawn!
>
> You have been cut down to the earth,
>
> You who have weakened the **nations!**

This is a reference to **Babylon** in the context, and in 14:12 it also mentions "**nations**".

**Isaiah 14:4a** ([NASB](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah%2014%3A4&version=NASB))

> that you will take up this taunt against the **king of Babylon**, and say,

Basically, Babylon once ruled nations, then lost it all. V12 refers to Babylon ('you') as the star of the morning. So...

### "ruler of nations" = "star of the morning"

So, it looks like Jesus is saying:

### "I will give him rule of the nations."

That's a reasonable theory, at least to weigh up against other study. So, let's test the theory...

You're in Revelation 2:28. Go back and look at 2:26-27

**Revelation 2:26-27** ([NASB](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation%202%3A26-27&version=NASB), emphasis added)

> 26 'He who overcomes, and he who keeps My deeds until the end, TO HIM I WILL GIVE ***AUTHORITY OVER THE NATIONS***;
> 27 AND HE SHALL ***RULE*** THEM WITH A ROD OF IRON, AS THE ***VESSELS OF THE POTTER ARE BROKEN TO PIECES***, as I also have received ***authority*** from My Father;

There you go. It all agrees. Now, you have something to study for the next ten years (because Bible study never ends). ;-)

---

*Additional note:*

### Kings 'break pottery'

*"Breaking pottery" is something invading kings would do when asserting power over a conquered people. "Breaking clay vessels" is also the act of a ruler with authority over government. Consider what my awesome prof, [Walton, says about pottery in Psalm 2:9 in his IVP Bible Background Commentary](https://books.google.com.tw/books?id=wIA3tH9HqY4C&pg=PA519&lpg=PA519&dq=as%20the%20pottery%20is%20dashed%20bible%20kings&source=bl&ots=OYJ3pLjv3l&sig=ACfU3U0bahyyeLHsovfQIOY1hfXEPn7MCA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj_idTsjfnfAhVIOrwKHVn1Bj0Q6AEwBnoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=as%20the%20pottery%20is%20dashed%20bible%20kings&f=false).*

*Breaking pottery is also a Biblical reference to [Jeremiah 19:1-11](https://newchristianbiblestudy.org/bible/story/the-potters-vessel-broken/king-james-version), also the act of a king.*

Comment: I think you have earlier mentions of morning stars in Job 38:7.

Answer (score 1):

Given the context, and I’ve not done much research on this specifically, the expression sounds to me to be **a rank title **and not an object.

> “Those who have insight will shine brightly like the brightness of the expanse of heaven, and those who lead the many to righteousness, like the stars forever and ever.”
>   ‭‭Daniel‬ ‭12:3‬ ‭NASB‬‬

Daniel allures to the brightness for those who awake for eternal life. Brightness levels are indicative of rank apparently. In the text you quoted it’s The Star, not just any star. It’s the highest rank you can attain.

It’s a similar idea here in the verses prior, quoting from Psalm 2

> “He who overcomes, and he who keeps My deeds until the end, TO HIM I WILL GIVE AUTHORITY OVER THE NATIONS; AND HE SHALL RULE THEM WITH A ROD OF IRON, AS THE VESSELS OF THE POTTER ARE BROKEN TO PIECES, as I also have received authority from My Father;”
>   ‭‭Revelation‬ ‭2:26-27‬ ‭NASB

Jesus is saying I will share my authority with him that overcomes.

I will give him the rank of The bright morning star.

To be given the bright morning star is to be given the honor of high(est) rank for overcoming. It’s Jesus’ acknowledgment of your obedience to Him.

I suppose it’s like saying in military terms, I will give him the Medal of Honor. That medal name is self explanatory but The Purple Heart medal isn’t self explanatory. If someone were to read “I will give you a Purple Heart” without the context or an explanation, it would seem odd. In this case overcoming the world and holding fast to His works, the bright morning star ranking, authority and honor will be bestowed upon the conqueror otherwise, it would appears to mean, He will give him Venus the morning star.

> “"I, Jesus, have sent My angel to testify to you these things for the churches. I am the root and the descendant of David, the bright morning star."”
>   ‭‭Revelation‬ ‭22:16‬ ‭NASB‬‬

Without context it could also appear that Jesus is giving the conquerer Himself. But again I think what Jesus is saying here is, Inam the bright morning star or I am the highest ranking and most powerful conquerer.

Comment: Could the downvoter please give a short explanation that I may correct myself and not remain ignorant. Thank you and thank you for voting

Comment: I've never heard it put quite that way before, but it's interesting.

Answer (score 0):

> Rev 2:28 (NIV) To the one who conquers I will also give the morning star.

**In Rev 2:28, what does it mean to be given the bright morning star?**

What came to mind when I read your question was:  'Early to bed and early to rise makes and man healthy, wealthy and wise'. So, in light of this old adage, which probably is based on the below Bible verses, I would say that "to be given the bright morning star" means to be given the Holy Spirit.

> Sirach 31:20 (NRSV) Healthy sleep depends on moderate eating; he rises early, and feels fit.
>
> Sirach 32:14 (NRSV) The one who seeks God will accept his discipline, and those who rise early to seek him will find favor.
>
> 1 Thess 4:8 (NIV) "those who get drunk, get drunk at night".

---

https://horvathliviu.wordpress.com/2011/09/10/john-stott-2/

Comment: +1 Short and to the point...Holy Spirit. Plus lines from Sirach I'd never read but would do well to heed.

Answer (score 0):

**To "receive the morning star" is to receive a spirit of wisdom and revelation.**

My understanding before attempting to answer this question was that the "morning star" represented Venus, the brightest object in the night sky (other than the moon). At the time of this writing I'm not seeing that position taken and I found this which is well supported, however I'll explain why I don't really find it compelling.

In this view from the [Baker Encyclopedia of the Bible](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2940926-baker-encyclopedia-of-the-bible). It equates the "morning star" with the "sun":

> Morning Star. Literally, the sun (Gn 1:14–18; Jb 38:7; Pss 19:4–6; 110:3); symbolically, a figure of speech which Christ used to describe himself (Rv 22:16). The phrase is closely related to the idea of the “dayspring” (Jb 38:12; Lk 1:78) and the “daystar” (2 Pt 1:19), all of which denote the rising of the sun in the morning. The symbolic application of the phrase to Christ is rooted in the OT (Nm 24:17) where Balaam prophesied, “I see him, but not now; I behold him, but not nigh; a star shall come forth out of Jacob.” Having clearly identified “the star” as a person from the family of Jacob, the later prophets develop this theme. Isaiah tells the people of his day to “rise and shine” because “the Lord will rise upon you” (Is 60:1, 2). Malachi writes, “For you who fear my name the sun of righteousness shall rise, with healing in its wings” (Mal 4:2). Zechariah, the father of John the Baptist, describes the ministry of his son as that of preparing the way for “the day shall dawn upon us from on high” (Lk 1:78); and we are told that he prepared the way for Christ (Mt 3:3; Mk 1:2, 3; Jn 1:6–8, 23; cf. Mt 11:7–14; Lk 7:18–28). The identity of the star is settled when Christ says, “I am the morning star” (Rv 22:16). It is another way of saying, “I am the light of the world” (Jn 8:12; 9:5; 12:46). The central concept found in the symbol is that of Christ as light shining in darkness (Lk 2:32; Jn 1:4, 7–9; 3:19; 12:35; 2 Cor 4:6; Eph 5:14; 1 Pt 2:9; 1 Jn 2:8; Rv 21:23). With the birth of the Messiah the morning star arose—the gospel light dawned (Is 9:1, 2; Mt 4:15, 16).
>   Christ not only describes himself as the morning star but declares that he gives the morning star (Rv 2:28). He bestows his own light upon those who believe in him (Jgs 5:31; Is 60:3; Dn 12:3; Mt 5:14, 16; Jn 1:9; Acts 13:47; Eph 5:8; Phil 2:5; 1 Thes 5:5; 1 Jn 1:7). In this sense Peter states that “the morning star [KJV daystar] rises in your hearts” (2 Pt 1:19). Because Christ has come and established his kingdom of light on earth, that light can abide in the minds of humankind.
>   The phrase then points to Christ’s glory, as the source of light, and to his grace in the sharing of light.
>
> Elwell, W. A., & Beitzel, B. J. (1988). In Baker encyclopedia of the Bible. Grand Rapids, MI: Baker Book House.
>   Exported from Logos Bible Software, 6:14 PM January 18, 2019.

What I find unsatisfying about this article is that it does not account for the other celestial bodies; the moon and the stars. The sun, moon and stars appear in the scriptures from the first page to the last. In Genesis 1 the sun, moon and stars are set in the heavens. The sun is said to "rule the day". This seems to be God (IE: the Father). [The moon, which reflects the sun (IE: actually 20% of it), the Messiah.](http://Heb%201:3%20DBY%20-%203%20who%20being%20the%20effulgence%20of%20his%20glory%20and%20the%20expression%20of%20his%20substance,%20and%20upholding%20all%20things%20by%20the%20word%20of%20his%20power,%20having%20made%20by%20himself%20the%20purification%20of%20sins,%20set%20himself%20down%20on%20the%20right%20hand%20of%20the%20greatness%20on%20high,) And the stars, the more disperse "the prophets".

In Job, the morning stars are plural:

> Job 38:7 KJV - 7 When the [morning](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=H1242&t=KJV) [stars](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=H3556&t=KJV) sang together, and all the sons of God shouted for joy?
>   28 tn Heb “the stars of its dawn.” The word נֶשֶׁף (neshef) can mean “twilight” or “dawn.” In this context the morning stars are in mind. Job wishes that the morning stars—that should announce the day—go out.
>
> Biblical Studies Press. (2006). The NET Bible First Edition Notes (Job 3:9). Biblical Studies Press.

Because the orbit of what we call "the planet Venus" is faster than that of what we call the "earth" it will sometimes be seen in the East and sometimes in the West. [It appears as the brightest body in the Northern hemisphere (I don't know about the South) both in the morning and in the evening.](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2940926-baker-encyclopedia-of-the-bible) **when the sun and moon are absent**:

> Eze 32:7 KJV - 7 And when I shall put thee out, I will cover the heaven, and make the stars thereof dark; I will cover the sun with a cloud, and the moon shall not give her light.
>   Eze 32:8 KJV - 8 All the bright lights of heaven will I make dark over thee, and set darkness upon thy land, saith the Lord GOD.

However, the ancients did not seem to understand that it was actually a rock with no light of its own. Also, being, in our terminology a "planet" rather than a "star" they called these moving "stars", "wanderers".

> ...Venus orbits the Sun faster than the Earth so it will either appear in the sky in the West in the evening or rise before the Sun in the East...

As [Dr. Michael Heiser](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jy-zIYjrnCA) has ably shown, the scriptures are peppered with revelations in the stars. These are not pagan consultations but rather divine communication mediated by his holy prophets. The prophets then, are "stars" shining in the sky and like the sun in his strength illuminating all the world:

> Psa 19:1-4 NIV - 1 For the director of music. A psalm of David. The heavens declare the glory of God; the skies proclaim the work of his hands. 2 **Day after day they pour forth speech; night after night they reveal knowledge.** 3 They have no speech, they use no words; no sound is heard from them. 4 Yet their voice[see footnote below from [Berean Study Bible]](https://biblehub.com/bsb/psalms/19.htm#) goes out into all the earth, their words (ῥήματα) to the ends of the world. In the heavens God has pitched a tent for the sun.
>
> **4 a LXX, Jerome and Syriac; Hebrew their measuring line**

Paul quotes the LXX in Romans to refer to the apostle and prophets:

> Rom 10:16-18 KJV - 16 But they have not all obeyed the gospel. For Esaias saith, Lord, who hath believed our report? 17 So then faith cometh by hearing, and hearing by the word (ῥήματος) of God. 18 But I say, Have they not heard? Yes verily, their sound went into all the earth, and their words unto the ends of the world.

However, in describing the "speech" and the "words" (ῥήματα) of the heavens he shows that he is really talking about God's apostles and prophets by relating them to the scriptures:

> 7The law [IE: instruction] of the LORD is perfect,
>   reviving the soul;
>   the testimony of the LORD is trustworthy,
>   making wise the simple.
>   8The precepts of the LORD are right,
>   bringing joy to the heart;
>   **the commandments of the LORD are radiant,
>   giving light to the eyes.**
>   9The fear of the LORD is pure,
>   enduring forever;
>   the judgments of the LORD are true,
>   being altogether righteous.
>   10They are more precious than gold,
>   than much pure gold;
>   they are sweeter than honey,
>   than honey from the comb.
>   11By them indeed Your servant is warned;
>   in keeping them is great reward.
>   12Who can discern his own errors?
>   Cleanse me from my hidden faults.

So it appears that God speaks through signs in the heavens, through the prophets and the "morning star" is Venus, which is also the "evening star".

**So to "receive the morning star" is to receive a spirit of wisdom and revelation.**

But the quintessential verse, I believe, that reflects the sense in which Jesus intended his promise is this:

> 2Pe 1:19 NKJV - 19 And so we have the prophetic word confirmed, which you do well to heed as a light that shines in a dark place, until the day dawns and the morning star rises in your hearts;

Notice that he does not say, "The scriptures have been fulfilled so that now we no longer need them." Au contraire he is saying that the words of the apostles and prophets have been demonstrated to be reliable so we should depend on them more and more. As the prophecies about Christ become more "solid" through the brief, secret (they were alone) revelation so to those who ruminate on the scriptures Christ will appear in glory by a spirit of wisdom and revelation in the knowledge about him.

I should note the word "bright" (λαμπρός) in "bright and morning star" also has the usage "clear" and "transparent" in verse 1:

> ΑΠΟΚΑΛΥΨΙΣ ΙΩΑΝΝΟΥ 22:1 Greek NT: Westcott and Hort / [NA27 and UBS4 variants]
>   καὶ ἔδειξέν μοι ποταμὸν ὕδατος ζωῆς **λαμπρὸν ὡς κρύσταλλον**, ἐκπορευόμενον ἐκ τοῦ θρόνου τοῦ θεοῦ καὶ τοῦ ἀρνίου

NASB Rev 22:1 Then he showed me a river of the water of life, **clear as crystal**, coming from the throne of God and of the Lamb,

IE: "crystal clear"!:

> STRONGS NT 2986: λαμπρός
>
> λαμπρός, λαμπρά, λαμπρόν (λάμπω);
>   a. shining; brilliant: ἀστήρ, Revelation 22:16 (Homer, Iliad 4, 77, etc.); **clear, transparent, Revelation 22:1.**
>
> b. splendid, magnificent (A. V. gorgeous, bright (see below)): ἐσθής, Luke 23:11; Acts 10:30; James 2:2f; λίνον (L Tr WH λίθον), Revelation 15:6; βύσσινος, ; neuter plural splendid ((R. V. sumptuous)) things, i. e. elegancies or luxuries in dress and style, Revelation 18:14. The word is sometimes used of brilliant and glistening whiteness (hence, λαμπρά τηβεννα, toga candida, Polybius 10, 4, 8; 10, 5, 1); accordingly the Vulg. in Acts 10:30; James 2:2; Revelation 15:6 renders it bycandidas; and some interpreters, following the Vulg. (indutum vestc alba), understand 'white apparel' to be spoken of in Luke 23:11 (A. V. gorgeous; (see above)); cf. Keim, iii., p. 380 note (English translation, vi. 104).

We also use Peter's word for revelation: "it just **dawned** on me that...". It isn't the sun in its strength but the sure word of the prophets in a spirit of revelation:

> Eph 1:18 KJV - 18 The eyes of your understanding being enlightened; that ye may know **what is the hope** of his calling, and what the riches of the glory of his inheritance in the saints,

I notice also (and I realize Eutychus isn't breathing) in verse 2 that he describes trees beside a river that bear 12 manner of fruit. What might these be other than the trees of God's planting:

> Rev 22:2 KJV - 2 In the midst of the street of it, and on either side of the river, was there the tree of life, which bare twelve manner of fruits, and yielded her fruit every month: and the leaves of the tree were for the healing of the nations.
>
> Psa 1:1-3 KJV - 1 Blessed is the man that walketh **not in the counsel of the ungodly**, nor standeth in the way of sinners, nor sitteth in the seat of the scornful. 2 But **his delight is in the law of the LORD; and in his law doth he meditate day and night**. 3 And he shall be **like a tree planted by the rivers of water, that bringeth forth his fruit in his season**; his leaf also shall not wither; and whatsoever he doeth shall prosper.

In the Catholic versions (not Protestant versions) of the scriptures there are 12 fruits of the spirit that are listed in Galatians:

> The 12 fruits are charity (or love), joy, peace, patience, benignity (or kindness), goodness, longanimity (or long-suffering), mildness (or gentleness), faith, modesty, continency (or self-control), and chastity. (Longanimity, modesty, and chastity are the three fruits found only in the longer version of the text.)
>   https://www.thoughtco.com/the-fruits-of-the-holy-spirit-542103

If so then the "12 manner of fruit" on the "tree(s) of life on either side of the river that flows from the throne of God and of the Lamb" again come to fruition as we ruminate on the scriptures and they become clear as crystal. As Jesus appeared in a purity that no soap could produce so to the one who meditates on the scriptures will "see" Jesus in glory as well.

Regardless of whether it is Venus or the Sun it refers to the spirit of revelation conferred on those Jews of the new covenant who ruled over Israel in her final days as a covenant people:

> Rev 2:27 KJV - 27 And he shall rule them with a rod of iron; as the vessels of a potter shall they be broken to shivers: even as I received of my Father.
>
> Mat 19:28 KJV - 28 And Jesus said unto them, Verily I say unto you, That ye which have followed me, in the regeneration when the Son of man shall sit in the throne of his glory [33ad], ye also shall sit upon twelve thrones, judging the twelve tribes of Israel.

The apostles ruled righteously because they had the Torah written upon their hearts. Then they were gathered home, Israel's earthly temple was destroyed and they ceased to be God's covenant people.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88508/discussion-on-answer-by-ruminator-in-rev-228-what-does-it-mean-to-be-given-the).

Answer (score 0):

Peace to you.

The bright and morning star….translated as the “day star” here in 2nd Peter 1 19….is the witness of God arising within our hearts that this is the beloved Son speaking whom we are to hear.

> 2 Peter 1:16-21 KJV (16)  *For we have not followed cunningly devised
>   fables, when we made known unto you the power and coming of our Lord
>   Jesus Christ, but were eyewitnesses of his majesty.*

The apostles on the holy mount heard a voice which came from Heaven saying “This is my beloved Son, in whom I am well pleased”.

> *(17)  For he received from God the Father honour and glory, when there
>   came such a voice to him from the excellent glory, **This is my beloved
>   Son, in whom I am well pleased.** (18)  And this voice which came from
>   heaven we heard, when we were with him in the holy mount.*

But today, we have a more “sure word of prophecy” as the witness of God about the Son is within our very own hearts:  the arising Light within our once darkened hearts.

The Lord comes to open up the Scriptures to our minds and we have the witness within us that this is His beloved Son speaking:  the Light that shines in a dark place (the heart).   The “day star”…..the MORNING STAR….arises in our hearts and serves as the personal witness to us that this is His beloved Son speaking (whom we are to hear).

> *(19)  We **have also a more sure word of prophecy; whereunto ye do well
>   that ye take heed, as unto a light that shineth in a dark place, until
>   the day dawn, and the day star arise in your hearts**:*

Holy men of God spoke as they were moved by the Holy Spirit….and still do today as the Lord sends them out to speak His words of life and spirit as the Lord opens up the Scriptures  to our ears in the correct interpretation of them.   We are to take heed on how we hear.

It will not conform to what the word of men has been preaching and will cause many to disagree with what they hear as a result.  But let God be true and every man a liar.

> *(20)  Knowing this first, **that no prophecy of the scripture is of any
>   private interpretation.** (21)  For the prophecy came not in old time by
>   the will of man: **but holy men of God spake as they were moved by the
>   Holy Ghost**.*

He will give the morning star to those who can overcome and keep His works to the end.   That is, He will give the morning star to those who will hear you speak His words.

When one speaks His words of life and spirit to others, then the “morning star” will arise in the hearts of those who will hear you.  He will give you the morning star ….in others’ hearts as they hear you speak….. if we can overcome and we shall rule with Him.

> Revelation 2:26-28 *KJV (26)  And he that overcometh, and keepeth my
>   works unto the end, to him will I give power over the nations: (27) 
>   And he shall rule them with a rod of iron; as the vessels of a potter
>   shall they be broken to shivers: even as I received of my Father. (28)
>   **And I will give him the morning star**.*

We can then be His messenger to others.  He sends His messenger out to speak to the churches …and He is the “morning star” that arises in the hearts of those who will hear His messenger.

> Revelation 22:16-17 *KJV (16)  I Jesus have sent mine angel to testify
>   unto you these things in the churches. I am the root and the offspring
>   of David, **and the bright and morning star.***

Those who hear are to be found hospitable towards those whom messengers that He will send out.  Whoever hears the messengers, hears Him.

They will be found inviting (“come”).  They will let brotherly love continue and will remember to entertain strangers and their words (or rather, His words).

> (17)  *And the Spirit and the bride say, Come. **And let him that heareth
>   say, Come.** And let him that is athirst come. And whosoever will, let
>   him take the water of life freely.*

Those who are truly sent of the Lord (those not preaching themselves) have this effect upon our very own hearts:  the light shines out of darkness….shining in our hearts…. when we hear them speak His words.

> *2 Corinthians 4:5-6 KJV (5)  For we preach not ourselves, but Christ
>   Jesus the Lord; and ourselves your servants for Jesus' sake. (6)  F**or
>   God, who commanded the light to shine out of darkness, hath shined in
>   our hearts,** to give the light of the knowledge of the glory of God in
>   the face of Jesus Christ.*

The truly anointed people will rule with the Lord.

> *2 Samuel 23:1-7 KJV (1)  Now these be the last words of David. David
>   the son of Jesse said, and the man who was raised up on high, the
>   anointed of the God of Jacob, and the sweet psalmist of Israel, said,*

They will speak His words in His Spirit.

> (2)  ***The Spirit of the LORD spake by me, and his word was in my
>   tongue.*** (3)  The God of Israel said, the Rock of Israel spake to me,
>   He that ruleth over men must be just, ruling in the fear of God.

The truly anointed with the Spirit...like David was... will speak and the “morning star” will arise in those who will hear the truly anointed speaking.  He shall be as the “light of the morning”….when the sun arises (in the hearts of those who will hear)…

> *(4)  **And he shall be as the light of the morning, when the sun riseth,
>   even a morning without clouds;** as the tender grass springing out of
>   the earth by clear shining after rain. (5)  Although my house be not
>   so with God; yet he hath made with me an everlasting covenant, ordered
>   in all things, and sure: for this is all my salvation, and all my
>   desire, although he make it not to grow. (6)  But the sons of Belial
>   shall be all of them as thorns thrust away, because they cannot be
>   taken with hands: (7)  But the man that shall touch them must be
>   fenced with iron and the staff of a spear; and they shall be utterly
>   burned with fire in the same place.*

The presence (coming) of the Son of man is obvious to those who hear Him speak.  The “lightning” comes out of the “east”….the rising of light within the heart….and shines unto the “west”….where the sun had gone down (the darkness)  The Light shines out of the darkness of the heart as the breaking of the light of the sun in the early dawn.

> *Matthew 24: (27)  **For as the lightning cometh out of the east, and
>   shineth even unto the west; so shall also the coming of the Son of man
>   be.***

This distinguishes those who are truly sent from the false apostles.   False apostles (falsely sent) glory as that they are truly sent of Him but are not.  They preach themselves only.

They say they are anointed with the Spirit to speak to our ears but they are not. They are of the spirit of the “antichrist”….the instead –of-anointed….that seeks to deceive us and lead us away from the Way that leads to His eternal life in this earth.   **The arising bright and morning star within our hearts does not accompany their deceptive words to us.**

They instead have to rely upon showing us great signs and wonders to seduce us.   They show us/perform outward signs (such as performing literal water baptism…which is a BIG sign today)  of supposed inward realities (behold, He is in the inner chambers) .

They show us “wonders” . They speak great swelling words of emptiness in order to seduce us into keeping company with them in their churches where they can make a gain from us.

> Matthew 24:23-27 KJV *(23)  Then if any man shall say unto you, Lo,
>   here is Christ, or there; believe it not. (24)  **For there shall arise
>   false Christs, and false prophets, and shall shew great signs and
>   wonders;** insomuch that, if it were possible, they shall deceive the
>   very elect. (25)  Behold, I have told you before. (26)  **Wherefore if
>   they shall say unto you, Behold, he is in the desert; go not forth:
>   behold, he is in the secret chambers; believe it not.** (27)  For as the
>   lightning cometh out of the east, and shineth even unto the west; so
>   shall also the coming of the Son of man b*e.

Their mouth speaks great swelling words having men’s persons in “admiration”….that is, “wonders”….because of gain.

> Jude 1:16 KJV (16)  *These are murmurers, complainers, walking after
>   their own lusts; and their mouth speaketh great swelling words, **having
>   men's persons in admiration** because of advantage.*

Answer (score -1):

There's much that could be said on this subject but I like neither to read nor write overly long posts. Jesus means that He will give them the eternally enduring light in their hearts; Himself.

> Revelation 22:16 “I, Jesus, have sent my angel to testify to you about these things for the churches. I am the root and the descendant of David, THE Bright Morning Star.”

Comment: So if he gives them THE morning star then what about the next guy that overcomes? Also, on this site they DO prefer longer answers. https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: You're right, I should've explained more. In Rev. 2 Jesus refers to ALL who overcome; 26 To the one (any-all) who is victorious and does my will to the END . . .  27 that one (any-all) ‘will rule them with an iron scepter . . . just as I have received authority from my Father. 28 I will also give that one (any-all) the morning star.
The reward for the redeemed is to be translated into bodies that are ONE with the Father and Son just as the Son is ONE with the Father now - we will be as they are. I assume that the majority of those participating in a forum like this aren't novices in theology.